# How can I change size of input control in metro ui?

Tags: css, input, microsoft-metro, metro-ui-css

how can I control size of inputs in Metro UI Framework? Bootstrap has class form-group-sm i guess, but have MetroUI something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MetroUI isn't as fully featured as Bootstrap but it has some simple [options for inputs](https://metroui.org.ua/inputs.html):

```
<!-- Checkbox -->
<label class="input-control checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="caption">Checkbox</span>
</label>
<!-- Small Checkbox -->
<label class="input-control checkbox small-check">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="caption">Checkbox</span>
</label>
<!-- Radio button -->
<label class="input-control radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="caption">Radio</span>
</label>
<!-- Small radio button -->
<label class="input-control radio small-check">
    <input type="radio">
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="caption">Small radio</span>
</label>
```

Text boxes can be default or big:

```
<div class="input-control text big-input">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

It also provides a couple of simple options for [buttons](https://metroui.org.ua/buttons.html):

```
<button class="button">Caption</button>
<button class="button mini-button">Caption</button>
<button class="button small-button">Caption</button>
<button class="button large-button">Caption</button>
```